# How to make ReactiveCommand synchronous?

Tags: winforms, reactiveui

I am trying to use ReactiveUI 6.5 for WinForms.

I need a command that is invoked on the viewmodel and executed synchronously on the view. I tried `ReactiveCommand.Create()` and `.Execute()`, but this is obviously  executed async, which is not what I need.

What I have is something like this:

```
public class MyViewModel : ReactiveObject
{
    public ReactiveCommand<object> AddNewThingToControl { get; private set; }

    public ThingType Thing { get; set; }

    // Ctor
    public MyViewModel()
    {
        AddNewThingToControl = ReactiveCommand.Create();
    }

    // Thing factory, called from somwhere not shown
    public void CreateAndAddThing()
    {
        Thing = new ThingType();

        // should not return before Thing is added to myControl
        AddNewThingToControl.Execute(null); 

        // Code that needs Thing added to myControl goes here.
        // This doesn't work because DoAddThing() has not been called yet!   
    }
}

public class MyView : Form, IViewFor<MyViewModel>
{
    public MyViewModel VM { get; set; }

    // Ctor
    public MyView()
    {
        VM = new MyViewModel();
        VM.AddNewThingToControl.Subscribe(x => { DoAddThing(); });
    }

    private void DoAddThing()
    {
        // This doesn't get called until some unknown time
        // after AddNewThingToControl.Execute() returns!
        myControl.Things.Add(VM.Thing);     
    }

    // -----------
    #region IViewFor Implementation not shown
}
```

`CreateAndAddThing()` is called by code either on the UI-thread or from some kind of worker thread.

A new `Thing` is created and should be added to the control on the view before the line after `AddNewThingToControl.Execute()` is reached.

How can I do this with `ReactiveCommand`?

Answer (score 2):

- Make `MethodThatNeedsThingAdded()` to return `Task`, in order to be awaitable.
- Make the `CreateAndAddThing()` method `async`, and `await` first for the execution of the command, and then for the `MethodThatNeedsThingAdded()`.
- Don't call `Execute` on the `ReactiveCommand`, but `ExecuteAsyncTask` which is awaitable!

This could be the code:

```
public async void CreateAndAddThing()
{
    Thing = new ThingType();
    await AddNewThingToControl.ExecuteAsyncTask(null);
    await MethodThatNeedsThingAdded();
}
```

This solution is elegant, clear, and you're sure that the two methods are always called in the right order. So to speak, the whole work is asynchronous respect to the UI Thread, but is sequential and predictable as you want.

You will say: "but I wanted all this round to be synchronous!". Do you *really* need a synchronous execution? For what purpose? If you *really* need this, imho you've chosen the wrong library. Try to implement a `Command` class on your own (deriving from `ICommand` as needed by WPF controls).